# Error Build for Testing when run command pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've a problem when I run "Build for Testing" on Xcode.

Step 0: In pod file using pod for target test as image below:

[image]

Step 1: Go to terminal and run command `pod install`.

Step 2: Go back to Xcode and touch tab bar Product -> Build for testing then the project warning error. 
[image]

I trying to fix it 2 days. Unfortunately, my project still error. I appreciate kind of support me to solve it.

Comment: `Build Phases` > `Search Path` remove all Paths setting, delete `DerivedData`, `Product` > `Clean`, `pod install` again then rebuild app.

Comment: @Tim007 On target testing or target identity?

Comment: In your main app target, try @Taj Ahmed answer, that can work too.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you run pod install it changes the build configuration.
go to **Project >> Build Settings** search for **architecture**.
then make sure you have the same configuration for **build active architectures only** in both places
1. your project build configuration
2. pods project build configuration

If they differ your project will not build

Comment: I tried set Build Active Architecture Only = Yes || No in 2 targets. It still same error before.

Comment: check it for projects as well as in targets configurations

Comment: Yes. I've changed for all targets on my project. But, the same error :(

Comment: try changing **Build Active Architecture Only** to NO in all build settings
if it doesn't work then you can try deleting `Pods/` directory and rerun pod install